# Como códigos proprietários ficam inacessíveis

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Como um software que não é livre, cujo usuário não tem acesso ao código fonte, consegue esconder seu código? O código não fica disponível de qualquer maneira no computador, já que tem de ser executado?

Comment: numa linguagem em que o resultado é compilado num executável, todo o teu código fica com você, e você apenas distribui o executável, que não tem mais a linguagem que você escreveu, mas sim, apenas instruções binárias, é muito difícil, complexo, custoso tentar editar algo assim, é praticamente impossível fazer reais edições em algo assim.

Answer (score 0):

## Há diferença entre código fonte e código objeto ou executável

O código fonte é aquele produzido por seres humanos com o apoio de linguagens de programação como Java ou C#, por exemplo.

Este código, se disponibilizado, facilita a extensão, modificação, cópia ou uso em outro cenário. Uma licença *open source*, como o próprio nome indica, significa que o código fonte (source) está disponível, acessível. Por outro lado, este código não pode ser executado por um computador. Código objeto ou binário é aquele equivalente ao código fonte, produzido por ferramentas conhecidas por compiladores. O código executável, binário, é uma sequência de zeros e uns, compreendida por um computador, mas inviável para consumo humano.

O código que está em execução no seu computador é binário, este, dificilmente é compreendido por seres humanos. Dificilmente será reutilizado em outro cenário, adaptado ou modificado. Não é impossível, mas o custo, em geral, é elevado, o que torna "inviável" a tentativa de fazer modificações ou outros usos.

Enfim, o código que está no seu computador é executável, e o esforço para obter o código fonte correspondente é oneroso, ou não apresenta bons resultados, mesmo quando auxiliado por ferramentas. Dito de outra forma, o que é "natural" para o computador é praticamente inacessível por um ser humano, ou seja, precisamos do código fonte.